# Is map_flex_1_20.swc library deprecated?

Tags: android, flash, google-maps, apache-flex

we have developed an application using flex builder 3 and we are using **map_flex_1_20.swc** library to display google maps and do other stuff in our application.According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/ link. From September 2, 2014, google MAP API for Flash will no longer be available.will this have any effect on my library?
will my library stop working and will not display google map or any request that will send from this library?

Can someone explain this to me please.Detail will be highly appreciated